# i'm creating a api in nest js with mongoose. i'm want to pass my state id in the city so what is the type of validation of state_id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

here is my citydto.ts

```
export class CityDto{
   
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    name:string

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Validate(Unique, [state_id])
     state_id:string

}
```

how can i apply the validation on stat_id. the state_id store directly with the name of city in my database but i want to validate my state_id???
here is my city.schema.ts file

```
export const CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    state_id:{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,unique:true}
  })
```

Comment: class-validator has ```@IsMongoId``` decorator which you can use for state_id